# Python 2.7 - Extracting information from a table and assigning it to a variable

Tags: python

I have a program that generates a table of X and Y values for points with different ID tags. Even though they have a different ID tag they can be of the same type. I want to add all the X and Y values that belong to the same type together.

The problem is I do not know how many types there will be until the table has been generated and I would like to know how to create a variable that corresponds to each type and then how I would cumulatively add the values together.

Here is the table I am working with:

```
ID  Type    X   Y 
10  1   34  23
11  1   34  54
12  1   42  4
13  1   76  3
14  1   35  56
15  1   23  4
16  2   56  5
17  2   46  6
18  2   35  77
19  3   75  6
20  3   54  7
21  3   43  6
```

This is an example of what I would like to achieve:

A unique variable is created for each type depending on the number of types. In this case I need 3 variables for types 1 -3.

```
Type_1_Total_X = 34+34+42+76+35+23 = 244
Type_2_Total_X = 56+46+35 = 137
```

I hope that is clear and I appreciate any help you can offer. If I can clear anything up please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: How does your code look so far? Can you include in the question?

Comment: What program is generating your table? Is that a Python program? Are the values stored in a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this helping you? I'm not sure how you get your table but I guess you can figure out to use the rest of this code in your program.

```
# Created a simple class for a row in your table
class Row(object):
    def __init__(self, i, t, x, y):
        self.i, self.t, self.x, self.y = int(i), int(t), int(x), int(y)

# Used your example rows...
example_rows = """10  1   34  23
11  1   34  54
12  1   42  4
13  1   76  3
14  1   35  56
15  1   23  4
16  2   56  5
17  2   46  6
18  2   35  77
19  3   75  6
20  3   54  7
21  3   43  6"""

# Build a list with rows from the example 'table'
l = [Row(*i) for i in (line.split() for line in example_rows.split("\n"))]

# Create a types_x dictionary
types_x = {}
for r in l:
    types_x[r.t] = types_x.get(r.t, 0) + r.x

# Print the result
print(types_x) # {1: 244, 2: 137, 3: 172}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I am very new to python. The code you have provided works perfectly but there are a couple of things I do not understand: When you (*i) does it automatically fill out the arguments for the class and secondly I do not understand the function types_x.get(r.t,0) + r.x and how it calculates the sum of the area. If you have time to answer I'd appreciate it but if not thanks again for your help! James

Comment: *... is used to parse arguments to a method or function. i is a list in this example, created with line.split(). types_x.get() is used to get the 'current' dictionary item, but value 0 when it's not found in the dictionary so it's 0 to begin with.  off-topic: When you want to parse keyword arguments, you could use **d (assuming that d is a dictionary and the function or method you are 'parsing too', is accepting keyword arguments).

Comment: I realize that I explained types_x.get() a little weird... To get a value from a dictionary you can use dict[key] but this raises an KeyError when the key doens't exists. The method .get() accepts a second argument which you can use as a 'default' value in case the key doens't exists, for example: dict.get(key, 'default_value'). In our case we use 0 as the default and start adding r.x

Comment: If you think the answer is useful, could you 'vote' on it?

Comment: Thanks joente for your explanation, it makes a lot more sense now. Unfortunately I need a reputation of at least 15 to vote but don't worry once I reach that I will vote your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using a list? Like

```
types_x[1] = 34+34+42+76+35+23
types_x[2] = 56+46+35
```

When a new type comes, you just need to `append` it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you would like to structure your data.

Here is an alternative:

```
>>> data_point = {}
>>> data_point[10] = (1, 34,  23 )
>>> data_point[11] = (1, 34,  54 )
>>> data_point[12] = (1, 42,  4  )
>>> data_point[13] = (1, 76,  3  )
>>> data_point[14] = (1, 35,  56 )
>>> data_point[15] = (1, 23,  4  )
>>> data_point[16] = (2, 56,  5  )
>>> data_point[17] = (2, 46,  6  )
>>> data_point[18] = (2, 35,  77 )
>>> data_point[19] = (3, 75,  6  )
>>> data_point[20] = (3, 54,  7  )
>>> data_point[21] = (3, 43,  6  )
```

All `X` values of type `1`:

```
>>> [x[1] for x in data_point.itervalues() if x[0] == 1]
[34, 34, 42, 76, 35, 23]
```

All `Y` values of type `1`:

```
>>> [x[2] for x in data_point.itervalues() if x[0] == 1]
[23, 54, 4, 3, 56, 4]
```

All `X` values of type `2`:

```
>>> [x[1] for x in data_point.itervalues() if x[0] == 2]
[56, 46, 35]
```

All `Y` values of type `2`:

```
>>> [x[2] for x in data_point.itervalues() if x[0] == 2]
[5, 6, 77]
```

.. and so on.

The sum you will get by using `sum()`:

```
>>> sum([x[1] for x in data_point.itervalues() if x[0] == 1])
244
>>> sum([x[2] for x in data_point.itervalues() if x[0] == 1])
144
>>> sum([x[1] for x in data_point.itervalues() if x[0] == 2])
137
>>> sum([x[2] for x in data_point.itervalues() if x[0] == 2])
88
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a dictionary where the keys are the type attribute of the table:

```
        #ID Type X   Y 
table="""10  1   34  23
11  1   34  54
12  1   42  4
13  1   76  3
14  1   35  56
15  1   23  4
16  2   56  5
17  2   46  6
18  2   35  77
19  3   75  6
20  3   54  7
21  3   43  6"""

summary = {}

for row in table.split('\n'):
    (id_, type_, x, y) = row.split()
    old_x, old_y = summary.get(type_, [0, 0])
    summary[type_] = [int(x) + old_x, int(y) + old_y]

print summary
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your data in the following structure:

```
data = {10: {'type': 1, 'x': 34, 'y': 23 },
        11: {'type': 1, 'x': 34, 'y': 54 },
        12: {'type': 1, 'x': 42, 'y': 4},
        16: {'type': 2, 'x': 56 ,'y': 5}}
```

For adding, use:

```
sum([item['x'] for item in data.itervalues() if item['type'] == 1])
#110
```

In this way you need not create a new variable for every type. and you can populate this dict as and when your program generates the table, by using:

```
data.update({new_id:{'y': y_val, 'x': x_val, 'type': type}})
```